# Install Homebrew package with all available options

Tags: install, homebrew

Is there a way to install a package and include all `--with*` options instead of typing all of them individually at the CLI?

To avoid:

```
brew install ffmpeg --with-chromaprint --with-fdk-aac ...
```

Comment: Note that per this answer, as of Homebrew 2.0 (Feb 2019), options are no longer supported by homebrew-core. Only third-party taps have options. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125129/how-do-i-give-options-to-homebrew-install

Answer (score 8):

Disclaimer: I'm not so familiar with grep. Smarter solutions are welcome.


You can list all options with this command.

```
brew options target_formula
```

And you can get all `--with-*` options with this.

```
brew options target_formula | grep 'with-'
```

So you can install a formula with all `--with-*` options by this.

```
brew install target_formula `brew options target_formula | grep 'with-'`
```

Note that some formula, especially in unofficial tap, can have old options not prefixed with `--with-` or `--without`.


EDIT:
If you want to exclude specific option, for example `--with-zimg`, you can do that with this.
(`grep -v 'with-zimg'` is fine, but `grep -v 'zimg'` is shorter)

```
brew install target_formula `brew options target_formula | grep 'with-' | grep -v 'zimg'`
```

Comment: I initially tried `brew install ffmpeg "$(brew options ffmpeg | grep 'with-')"`, which threw a warning: `Warning: ffmpeg: this formula has no --with-chromaprint`, followed by all of the remaining **with-** options, each on a new line. The last line read: `--with-zimg option so it will be ignored`. **ffmpeg** was then installed without any of the **with-** options.

Comment: I then tried to reinstall using backticks instead of "$()", and the installation process did not proceed past throwing the following warning:
`zimg: macOS El Capitan or newer is required.
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.`

I then tried once more using "$()" and the same result as the first installation attempt occurred.

Comment: Regarding the first comment, you shouldn't use `" "`. This will squash all option into one option `--with-chromaprint --with-fdk-aac ...`, which brew can't recognize properly.

Comment: Regarding the second comment, you have no way but installing `ffmpeg` without `--with-zimg`. See the edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no wildcard-expansion mechanism for arguments in Homebrew, so the possibility to select all options, would depend on the implementation of each formula.

Looking at the [`ffmpeg` formula code](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/ffmpeg.rb), each option is handled individually, so it is not possible using the current version.

You would have to modify the formula removing the conditionals in lines like:

```
args << "--enable-chromaprint" if build.with? "chromaprint"
```

Or add a global switch for all arguments; or change the logic to install all by default and make the switches for disabling options.